# list of supported backbones models

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I'm running the following example:

```
from transformers import TimmBackboneConfig, TimmBackbone

# Initializing a timm backbone
configuration = TimmBackboneConfig("resnet50")

# Initializing a model from the configuration
model = TimmBackbone(configuration)

# Accessing the model configuration
configuration = model.config
```

from [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/main_classes/backbones)

Now I want to use other backbone model from the supported list in the same page,

- BEiT
- BiT
- ConvNet
- ConvNextV2
- DiNAT
- DINOV2
- FocalNet
- MaskFormer
- NAT
- ResNet
- Swin Transformer
- Swin Transformer v2
- ViTDet

where can I find the dictionary from this list, I mean what is the string that I should use for each of the model?

For example:

- "ResNet" -> 'resnet50'
- "BEiT" -> ???

I have tried to search for it in the some of the links in the page and in google but didn't find this information anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

`timm.list_models()` returns a complete list of available models in timm:

```
import timm

timm.list_models()
```

More info about how you can list models can be found [here](https://timm.fast.ai/models#List-of-models-supported-by-timm). Similar resources can be found on the [HuggingFace website](https://huggingface.co/docs/timm/quickstart#list-models-with-pretrained-weights).

Specifically, the `transformers.TimBackbone` class checks if the string you pass is in `timm.list_models()`. Check the related code [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/ff76e7c2126ab26e5722f54640d44cab7e3dfdd4/src/transformers/models/timm_backbone/modeling_timm_backbone.py#L53).

Comment: Thanks, it brings me a step forward. But I still don't know which string to use for "BEiT" for example. I run model_names = timm.list_models(״* b * e * i * t *״) {without space};
print(model_names). And to only results are "mobilevit" and "swinv2_base_window". Anyway, thank you!

Comment: I mean all all beit/beitv2 models from the list getting exception, "RuntimeError: features_only not implemented for BEiT models."